# Can I connect an AP to the LAN port on a PC to provide a WLAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a PC running my server application and several iPad Clients, and therefore need a WLAN to connect them.

Can I simply plug an access point such as a Cisco Aironet 1602i into the LAN port of the PC to accomplish this?

Comment: do you have an existing wifi network that the iPads are on, and you need to join your server to it, or do you not have any wifi at all? why not just plug the AP into the switch you are using to connect your server to the rest of your network?

Comment: I just have the PC running the server client, and the iPads just need a wireless TCP connection this PC. No existing wifi, and no internet needed.

Comment: would certianly be more flexible to just put a wifi card in the server and install the AP on your local switch, but if you really want to save the 15$, then it can be done.

Comment: cost not an issue, just looking for the simplest (more reliable?) solution. What would the local switch be?

Comment: I assume your PC/Server has internet under normal circumstances. usually end devices like this plug into a network switch (often part of a router) to connect them to other devices on the network. switches are the backbone of a wired network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how Joel means it wouldn't be simple - it would be about as simple a wireless network as you can get.

You would need to get an AP which provides DHCP and DNS services (so a basic router would probably be better). Turn off any firewalls or allow access through them for the services you want and the iPads should be able to see the PC.

Make sure that the IPs for wireless devices are in the same subnet as those for the wired, so that the machines can see each other (or just connect the "server" over the wireless connection) and job done.

Comment: OK great, so an Apple Airport would be suitable?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to set it up this way, but it would not be "simple", and would include several caveats, including that your iPads would not have any other internet access.

Comment: Internet access is not needed. Why would it not be simple? How would I make it easier?